# vue v2 я хочу заполнить форму данными которые приходят с сервера

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuex

Версия vue (2.6)
Я не особо понимаю принцип но мне хочется заполнить форму начальными значениями с сервера
так чтобы их можно было изменить и отправить обновленные данные на сервер

Расскажите как мне правильно заполнить форму из input select чтобы можно было данные изменить и отправить их на сервер

(Знаю React.js)

Comment: а в чем сама проблема? то что вы написали это целый ряд действий

Answer (score 0):

Устройте двустороннее связывание <select v-model="myData> (myData это один из моделек описанных в data())

После того как получили данные просто измените эту модельку и ваш select должен изменится

Comment: Долго отвечали,
В целом мне пришлось хранить данные из vuex в data так как из за v-model vuex мутировался что не совсем мне нравилось 

а так можно было и без vuex обойтись